# regex for matching where parts of string are not same

Tags: regex, emacs

I've got something like this

```
stuff(123)=stuff(123)
stuff(23434)=stuff(234324)
```

I want to match all instances where the right hand side and left hand side differ.

I've got this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
\\(stuff([0-9]+)\\)=[^\\1]
```

Also, I'm trying to do this using emacs regex search.

Comment: What are you going to do once you find them?  There are ways around your problem, but "it depends."

Comment: @scottfrazer The instances where they don't match are of interest. There is more content on the rhs side of the string that needs to be analyzed by a human in cases where they don't match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your answer to my comment, I'd use `flush-lines`:

```
M-x flush-lines RET \(stuff([0-9]+)\)=\1 RET
```

Note that you only use single backslashes at the miniprompt

Answer (score 0):

`if(false==foo.match(/(stuff\([0-9]+\))=\1/)` is the sort of thing you want. Depends on your regex dialect. You can't `[^\\1]`, `[]` is a *character class*.

You may want to look into zero-width assertions. Again, it depends on your dialect.

Comment: I don't think emacs regex takes \1.

Comment: @Jingshao Chen \1 does work in emacs, I have used it in query-replace-regex

Comment: @anio Yes. You are right. Emacs does support \n. I think the main problem is that there is no one liner to do the logical NOT of regular expression. You may have to write a function to do that logic.